# Maverick Issue : While adding a subview on NSView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, osx-mavericks, addsubview

I have a NSView(outlet - detailsView) , upon that a NSSplitView (outlet - detailsSpiltView) and there are two subviews in the split view and in those subview there are different scroll view and table view.

```
NSView(detailsView)
|
NSSplitView(detailsSplitView)
|           |
NSView      NSView
|                 |
NSScrollView      NSScrollView
|                 |
NSTableView       NSTableVIew
```

On a certain condition I am adding a an error view on detailsView and on other conditions the table view would be populated:
The code for loading errorView is the following:

```
[self.errorView setFrame:[self.detailsSplitView frame]];
[self.errorView setBackgroundColor:ERR_BG_COLOR];
[self.errorView setAlphaValue:0.85];
[self.detailsView addSubview:self.errorView];
```

Its working perfectly in Mountain Lion but in Maverick the errorView is getting loaded behind the table views. 
I even tried to send the table views in back using code

```
[tableView1 sendToBack];
[tableView2 sendToBack];
[self.detailsView addSubview:self.errorView positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:self.detailsSplitView];
```

But still errorview is loading in the back of tableview.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code beneath the addSubView method and it worked:

```
--------
[self.detailsView addSubview:self.errorView];
[self.errorView setWantsLayer:YES];
```